# Merge Sort Cleanup

Tags: python, python-3.x, mergesort

I am re-learning my fundamental algorithms, and have been told my Python is overly verbose.
Can you take a look at my merge sort algorithm and let me know how you would clean it up and make it more *pythonic*, if applicable?

```
def merge(left,right):
    out = []
    l_rest = []
    i = left[0]
    while i is not None:
        if right:
            if i < right[0]:
                out.append(i)
                left.remove(i)
            else:
                out.append(right[0])
                right.remove(right[0])
        else:
            out.append(i)
            left.remove(i)

         if len(left) > 0:
             i = left[0]
         else:
             i = None
    for i in l_rest:
        out.append(i)
    for i in right:
        out.append(i)
    return out

def sort(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst

    left = sort(lst[:len(lst)//2])
    right = sort(lst[len(lst)//2:])
    return merge(left,right)
```

Comment: Your code seems to have a bug: it doesn't include the pivot in the result.

Comment: @SolomonUcko Thanks,  not sure I follow, but I will debug tonight.

Comment: Sorry, at first I thought it was quicksort. What I meant was that, for example, if I sort a list of the numbers 0-99, repeated 100 times, then shuffled, the 0s are missing.

Comment: why not just `out += l_rest + right` instead of `for i in l_rest: out.append(i);  for i in right: out.append(i)`

Comment: @SolomonUcko fixed, that was nasty.  Thanks.  I chose to fix that and not fix YuliaV's suggestion inline... Not sure the best practice for implementing incremental improvements, but I like their idea.

Answer (score -1):

Starting a wiki with the suggested edits in the comments so far.

```
def merge(left,right):
    out = []
    i = left[0]
    while i is not None:
        if right and i < right[0]:
            out.append(i)
            left.remove(i)
        else:
            out.append(right[0])
            right.remove(right[0])

         if len(left) > 0:
             i = left[0]
         else:
             i = None

    return out + left + right

def sort(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst

    left = sort(lst[:len(lst)//2])
    right = sort(lst[len(lst)//2:])
    return merge(left,right)
```